# Matlab: Integral & quadl function gives NaN

Tags: matlab, nan, integral

I am trying to get optimized values by using fmincon function.
In the optimization procedure, a 'integProb' function is integrated with quadl(or integral, alternatively) method.

but the quadl integration function with integProb returns NaN with warning:'Infinite or Not-a-Number function value encountered.' at some values of a, b, Vmat and Vj. but I don't know exactly what their values make quadl function return NaN because those values are decided in the fmincon optimization process.

Does anyone have any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

I would appreciate any help,

Thank you.

```matlab
quadl(@(e) integProb(e,j,k,Vmat,Vj),a,b,eps1);
```

```matlab
function [val]=integProb(e,j,k,Vmat,Vj);
len = length(e);
x=repmat(e+Vj,k,1)-Vmat(:,1:len);
x2 = normcdf(x); % need the sigma of j (the chosen product)
x2(j,:)=1; % we do not need this. See the integrand in our integration eqn
val = prod(x2).* normpdf(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your cost function you need to protect against *bad* values and return a high cost (telling the optimizer that they are bad values) if they occur,

```
function [val]=integProb(e,j,k,Vmat,Vj);
len = length(e);
x=repmat(e+Vj,k,1)-Vmat(:,1:len);
x2 = normcdf(x); % need the sigma of j (the chosen product)
x2(j,:)=1; % we do not need this. See the integrand in our integration eqn
val = prod(x2).* normpdf(e);

if isnan(val) || isinf(val) || ~isreal(val)
   val = 1e10; % or some other large value
end
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks you so much! I will try it.